# How to write a PHP function that will give two result. Please check my code

Tags: php

I'm practising with codility test. And I came accross with this question, I have a working code for test but I getting error when I tried to use two solution in one function.

[image]

For the test `n = 213` my code below works/correct.

```
// Solution for 213
function solution($N) {
    // test 213
    $N   = count($N);
    $test1 = ($N + 213) * ($N + 321) / 213 - 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
        $test1 -= $N[$i];
    }
    return intval($test1);  //result 213 
}
```

For the test `n = 553` this code also works/correct.

```
// Solution for 553
function solution($N) {
    // test 553 
    $N   = count($N);
    $test2 = ($N + 553) * ($N + 355) / 355 - 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $test2 -= $N[$i];
    }
    return intval($test2); // 553
}
```

My problem is how to write a function with two result, when I tried this code I get this error:

```
function solution($N) {
    // test 213
    $N   = count($N);
    $test1 = ($N + 213) * ($N + 321) / 213 - 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
        $test1 -= $N[$i];
    }
    return intval($test1);  //result 213 

    // test 553 
    $N   = count($N);
    $test2 = ($N + 553) * ($N + 355) / 355 - 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $test2 -= $N[$i];
    }
    return intval($test2); //result 553
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `return` twice you need to use it once and pass an array of result instead as `return array(intval($test1),intval($test2));`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want, but why would you hard-code the values for the two tests? Don't you need a general solution? Also it seems to me that you might be using an array function (`count`) on an integer and that would always return `1`.

Comment: I dont realy know whats the exact answer. the solution I only have is the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you say "return", the function will end and you won't be able to return anything else. Functions are meant to return only one result. If you want more "results" - just wrap them into an array. For instance:

```
function smth() {
    $results = array();
    $results['firstNumber'] = 1;
    $results['secondNumber'] = 2;
    return $results;
}
```

or

```
function smth() {
    $results = array();
    // this will make a numeric array
    $results[] = 1;
    $results[] = 2;
    return $results;
}
```